# imported package is not available in Play! framework template

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0, bean-validation

I have a Play 2.0 template with the following first lines:

```
@(item: Option[Item] = None,
    violations: java.util.Set[ConstraintViolation[Item]] = new util.HashSet[ConstraintViolation[Item]]())

@import java.util
@import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation
```

But the `ConstraintViolation` cannot be found and I get the error:

```
not found: type ConstraintViolation
```

The bean validation API itself is available in the application since I can use it in a controller. What can I do to import it in my template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either use the fully-qualified name, i.e. `@(item: Option[Item] = None,
    violations: java.util.Set[javax.validation.ConstraintViolation[Item]] = new util.HashSet[javax.validation.ConstraintViolation[Item]]())` or add to your general template imports in Build.scala, like this:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  templatesImport += "javax.validation.ConstraintViolation"
)
```

Comment: Wow, this very convenient.

Comment: Thank you. But why is it impossible to import the package? Is there a rule when importing is possible and when not?

Comment: Your import works, but it comes after the parameter list. So in the parameter list, the type is still unknown.

Comment: To summarize: it is a limitation of the Play template engine since a template constructor must be on the first line and thus cannot be preceded by an import.

Comment: Is Method 2 still valid today (Play 2.1.2)? I've added to Build.scala main: `templatesImport += "com.some.framework.comms.webservice.marketdata.model.InstrumentTO"` - this did not help. However, `@(results: List[com.some.framework.comms.webservice.marketdata.model.InstrumentTO])` in the template worked.

Comment: @Bachi Yes it does, but the correct word is `templateImports`, not `templatesImport`. Here is the documentation: https://github.com/playframework/twirl#template-files